# Display related images based on text name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Instead of  "Black and Green" **text**, We are displaying "Black & Green" **images** with help of below code.

[image]

What we want is this concept should work for **all colors**, for that one solution is i need to write **manual code** for **hundreds of colors** as like below to make it work for all colors. but i think this is wrong way , may be it may impact on performance, is there any better way to handle this ?

**Script :**

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var inner = Array();
    inner = jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label");
    for (i=0;i<inner.length;i++){
         var classN = inner[i].innerText;
          if (classN=="Black" || classN=="Green"){
               inner.eq(i).addClass(classN);
          }
     }
});
```

**Css for green :**

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.Green
{ 
     font-weight: normal; 
     width: 50px; 
     height: 50px; 
     border-radius: 50%; 
     background-image: url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/green.png") !important; 
     background-size: cover !important; 
     display: block; 
     color: transparent; 
     padding: 0 !important; 
     font-size: 0; 
}
```

**Css for black :**

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.Black
{ 
     font-weight: normal; 
     width: 50px; 
     height: 50px; 
     border-radius: 50%; 
     background-image: url("http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/custom/black.png") !important; 
     background-size: cover !important; 
     display: block; 
     color: transparent; 
     padding: 0 !important; 
     font-size: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts come to mind here:

- You are not properly using inheritance in your CSS.  You should probably have one definition for `.product-options ul.options-list .label>label` which contains every single CSS declaration except for the actual background image. As these will not change.  Then just have definitions for `.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.*` (where `*` is `green`, `black`, etc.) that are one line each (specifying `background-image`), as that is the only part that changes based on color.
- You might consider not using images at all in favor of pure CSS.  This could actually give the benefit of potentially not having to declare per-color CSS styles at all, in favor of just changing the background color value on the elements to one of the [valid CSS named colors](http://www.crockford.com/wrrrld/color.html). [Here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) are CSS-only examples for different shapes. This would actually perform better as there would be no images to download at all.
- Your variable names are not very meaningful. For example `inner` might better be called `labels` or similar (or `$labels` if you use the convention of pre-pending jQuery collections with `$`). Perhaps `color` instead of `classN`.
- You might need to give up hope of individually checking each label element text as being one of allowed color values. Or look to solutions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386090/validating-css-color-names) to provide validation that the color names are good.
- Since you are working against a jQuery collection,  you might consider using `$.each()` as your iterator rather than a `for` loop.

Combining these approaches might mean you can simplify your code down to:

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $labels = jQuery(" .product-options ul.options-list .label>label");
    $labels.each(function() {
        var color = $(this).text();
        // perhaps validate color here as noted above in link
        if(colorIsValid(color)) {
            $(this).css('background', color);
        } else {
            throw new RangeError('Unexpected color value.');
        }
    }
});
```